# How set localization for Zend_Dojo_Form elements?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo, zend-form, dijit.form

Lets say I have a simple form:

```
class Form_Simple extends Zend_Dojo_Form
{
  public function  init() {
    $this->addElements(array(
      new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_ValidationTextBox('name', array(
        'required'   => true,
        'label'      => 'Name:'
    ))
  }
}
```

"name" element is required so error message will be "this field is required". How change this message?

Answer (score 0):

You can localize the form labels just like in any other part of your application.

In your bootstrap file you have to setup the [**Zend_Locale**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.html) and [**Zend_Translate**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html) object. It will be avialable in your entire application.

E.g in your boostrap:

```
//init locale
        $translate = new Zend_Translate('gettext', 
                        APPLICATION_PATH.'/languages',null,
                        array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_FILENAME));

        $locale = new Zend_Locale();
        $locale->setLocale(Zend_Locale::BROWSER);
        $requestedLanguage = key($locale->getBrowser());

        if(in_array($requestedLanguage, $translate->getList())){
            $language = $requestedLanguage;
        }else{
            $language = 'en';
        }

        $translate->setLocale($language);
        $view->translate = $translate;
```

Since the setup is really detailed  and maybe complex I recommend you to watch this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwPgqla-cRk